# How to log list of Magento Events Being Called During Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not looking for an **arbitrary list of events** I want to see the order of events called (anywhere in the app not just core) during the checkout process with the ability to log.

Example: I am in the frontend and click checkout out go through the motion and there is **code** logging events being called on the backend somewhere.

> **Log list of the events called upon any action.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer, within this code in Mage.php I just add a log for the $name variable. Gives me the order of events and names in a specified log file

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{   //This log call
    Mage::log($name, null,'events.log');
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

events during order/checkout:

```
`core_copy_fieldset_customer_account_to_quote`

`core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_to_order`
`sales_convert_quote_to_order`
`core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_address_to_order`
`sales_convert_quote_address_to_order`
`core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_address_to_order_address`
`sales_convert_quote_address_to_order_address`
`sales_order_address_collection_set_sales_order`
`core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_payment_to_order_payment`
`sales_convert_quote_payment_to_order_payment`
`sales_order_payment_collection_set_sales_order`
`core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item`
`core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item_discount`
`sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item`
`sales_order_item_collection_set_sales_order`
`checkout_type_onepage_save_order`
`sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

`sales_quote_save_before`
`sales_quote_save_after`
`sales_quote_address_save_before`
`sales_quote_address_save_after`
`sales_quote_payment_save_before`
`sales_quote_payment_save_after`
`sales_order_save_before`
`sales_order_address_save_before`
`sales_order_address_save_after`
`sales_order_resource_save_attribute_before`
`sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after`
`sales_order_item_save_before`
`sales_order_item_save_after`

`sales_order_payment_save_before`
`sales_order_payment_save_after`
`sales_order_resource_update_grid_records`
`sales_order_resource_init_virtual_grid_columns`
`sales_order_save_after`
`sales_order_place_before`
`sales_order_payment_place_start`
`sales_order_status_history_collection_set_sales_order`

`sales_order_status_history_collection_load_before`

`sales_order_status_history_collection_load_after`
`sales_order_payment_place_end`
`sales_order_place_after`
`sales_order_status_history_save_before`
`sales_order_status_history_save_after`

`sales_quote_address_save_commit_after`
`sales_quote_payment_save_commit_after`
`sales_quote_save_commit_after`
`sales_order_address_save_commit_after`
`sales_order_item_save_commit_after`
`sales_order_payment_save_commit_after`
`sales_order_save_commit_after`
`sales_order_status_history_save_commit_after`
`sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`
`sales_model_service_quote_submit_after`
`checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`

`checkout_submit_all_after`
```

Comment: I am not looking for a list, I'm looking for a **how to**. There are custom modules ALSO calling events.

Comment: Ok, So you want to create your own event. Right? Or what you want to do exactly.